# SharePoint 2013 - Show and sync Outlook calendar

Tags: sharepoint-server, outlook, exchange

is there a way to show a Outlook calendar in a SharePoint calendar. I know, that you can overlay a Exchange calendar, but will this calender sync by itself ? 
Or is there another way to display the personal Outlook calendar in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the calendar will sync by itself after Outlook/SharePoint calendar sync.

[Outlook Calendar Integration](https://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/dynamicsconsultantsblog/archive/2013/05/20/sharepoint-2013-outlook-calendar-integration)

Comment: But showing/and sync a Outlook calendar in a SharePoint calendar isn't possible? Or how does it works? The main Problem with your solution is, that you have two calendars, this isnt what I want,